# How can I call a variable defined inside a function from another file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have the following file named as `calculo_indice.py`

```
import pandas as pd

def limites(df,n):
    n_sigma = n * df.valor_unitario.std()
    mean = df.valor_unitario.mean()
    lower_bound: float = mean - n_sigma
    upper_bound: float = mean + n_sigma
    return (lower_bound,upper_bound)


def indice(df):
    df['isOutlier'] = df['valor_unitario'].apply(lambda x: True if x < lower_bound or x > upper_bound else False)
    df = df[~df.isOutlier]
    df['indice'] = df['valor_unitario'].apply(lambda x: ((x-lower_bound)/(upper_bound-lower_bound))*2000)
    df = df.astype({'indice': 'int64'})
```

It is meant to calculate the lower and upper bounds of a column of a dataframe (the first function called `limites`) then calculate an index over those bounds (function called `indice`)

Running the `calculo_indice.py` file it all goes fine, but when running the original file that calls those functions, I get a `NameError`

I imported that file as `import calculo_indice as indice` and then called those functions like this:

`indice.limites(df, 2)`

`indice.indice(df)`

I also tried to `print(lower_bound)` thats why I tried to return

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Indice.py", line 19, in <module>
    indice.indice(df)
  File "C:\Users\...\calculo_indice.py", line 12, in indice
    df['isOutlier'] = df['valor_unitario'].apply(lambda x: True if x < lower_bound or x > upper_bound else False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\Indice\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4138, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2467, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:\Users\...\calculo_indice.py", line 12, in <lambda>
    df['isOutlier'] = df['valor_unitario'].apply(lambda x: True if x < lower_bound or x > upper_bound else False)
NameError: name 'lower_bound' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong?
Appreciate ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are only defined within the **local scope** of your `limites` function. If they need to also be defined within `indice` then you must pass them as an argument, that way they are then in scope:

I've also modified your `indice` function. First you need to return the DataFrame, that way you can assign your changes to a variable and have them actually take effect. Second, most of your `Series.apply` calls were inefficient, and there are vectorized alternatives that will act on the entire Series.

#### calculo_indice.py

```
def limites(df,n):
    n_sigma = n * df.valor_unitario.std()
    mean = df.valor_unitario.mean()
    lower_bound: float = mean - n_sigma
    upper_bound: float = mean + n_sigma
    return (lower_bound, upper_bound)


def indice(df, lower_bound, upper_bound):
    # Vectorized check
    df['isOutlier'] = ~df['valor_unitario'].between(lower_bound, upper_bound)
    df = df[~df.isOutlier]
    
    # Vectorized calculation
    df['indice'] = (df['valor_unitario']-lower_bound)/(upper_bound-lower_bound)*2000
    df = df.astype({'indice': 'int64'})
    
    return df
```

You would then call `limites`, define the returned values to some variables (as it returns the lower and upper bounds) and pass those variabels to `indice`

```
import calculo_indice as indice

# Assign lower bound and upper bound to variables `lb` and `ub` respectively
lb,ub = indice.limites(df, 2)

df = indice.indice(df, lower_bound=lb, upper_bound=ub)
```

Comment: Hi, @ALollz, thanks very much for your excellent explanation. It worked as I expected, but i'm getting another kind of error (I think it doesnt affect the results, but would be nice to clarify this error):
```A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['indice'] = (df['valor_unitario'] - lb) / (ub - lb) * 2000```

I changed lower and upper bounds to `lb` and `ub`

Comment: @mateusvl Oh that's a common problem, I'm not 100% sure what line causes it in this example, but my guess is if you change the line you slice to `df = df[~df.isOutlier].copy()` (so add on an explicit copy) it should fix everything